# ¿Como puedo resolver para no mede EmptyStackException?

Tags: java, netbeans, condiciones, estructuras-de-datos, excepciones

Hola tenho este ejercicio de programacion:
[image: Este es el ejericio de pilas]

mi duda es como hago para que siga el programa cuando me da  EmptyStackException porque cuando da esto se acaba el codigo intente con try catch pero creo que lo hice mal,
este ejemplo podria ser mas claro para explicar el ejercicio
ejemplo:

Entrada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi salida

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Salida que se espera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo:

```
 //package EstructuraDatos.EjericicosPilas;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.util.EmptyStackException;
 import java.util.Stack;

 class Stack1 {

static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

    int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    Stack<Integer> pila = new Stack<Integer>();

    boolean error = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

        String textos = br.readLine();
        String[] parts = textos.split(" ");
        String signo = parts[0];

        if (signo.equals("-")) {
            Integer objetoBorrado = null;
            
            if (!pila.isEmpty()) {
                
                objetoBorrado = pila.pop();
                System.out.println(objetoBorrado);

            } else {
                System.out.println("empty");
            }
            
            
            
            error = true;
            
        } else {
            int x = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
            pila.push(x);
            
        }
        
    }

    while (!error) {
        System.out.println("empty");
    }
  }
}
```

como puedo solucionar mi error en mi codigo, si alguien me ayuda estaria muy agradecido :D

Comment: Hay que validar el estado del stack antes de volver a hacerle pop :)

Comment: Listo ya lo cambie, asi debe funcionar gracias}

Comment: Recuerda compartir la respuesta a tu pregunta si la encuentras tú. Puedes escribir la respuesta e incluso, unas horas después, marcarla como la respuesta aceptada :)